# How do we get the current date in a PS file name qualifier using JCL?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

How do we get the current date in a PS file name qualifier using JCL?

Example out put file name: Z000417.BCV.TEST.D120713 (YYMMDD format).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done, but not necessarily in a straightforward manner.  The straightforward manner would be to use a [system symbol](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=symbols-what-are-system) in your JCL.  Unfortunately [this only works for batch jobs if it has been enabled for the job class](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=symbols-using-in-batch-jcl) on more recent versions of z/OS.

Prior to z/OS v2, IBM's stated reason this didn't work is that your job could be submitted on a machine in London, the JCL could be interpreted on a machine in Sydney, and the job could actually execute on a machine in Chicago.  Which date (or time) should be on the dataset?  There is no one correct answer, and so we all created *our own solutions* to the problem that incorporates the answer we believe to be correct for our organization.

If you are able to use system symbols in your batch job JCL, there is [a list of valid symbols](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=symbols-dynamic-system) available to you.

One way to accomplish your goal is to use a job scheduling tool.  I am familiar with Control-M, which uses what are called "auto-edit variables."  These are special constructs that the product provides.  The Control-M solution would be to code your dataset name as
Z000417.BCV.TEST.D%%ODATE.

Some shops implement a scheduled job that creates a member in a shared PDS.  The member consists of a list of standard JCL SET statements...

```
// SET YYMMDD=120713
// SET CCYYMMDD=20120713
// SET MMDDYY=071312
```

...and so on.  This member is created once a day, at midnight, by a job scheduled for that purpose.  The job executes a program written in that shop to create these SET statements.

Another answer is you could use [ISPF file tailoring](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-file-tailoring) in batch to accomplish your goal.  This would work because the date would be set in the JCL before the job was submitted.  While this will work, I don't recommend it unless you're already familiar with file tailoring and executing ISPF in batch in your shop.  I think it's kind of complicated for something this simple to accomplish in other ways outlined in this reply.

You could use a GDG instead of a dataset with a date in its name.  If what you're looking for is a unique name, that's what GDGs accomplish (among other things).

The last idea that comes to my mind is to create your dataset with a name not containing the date, then use a [Unix System Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-unix-system-services) script to construct an [ALTER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-alter) command (specifying the NEWNAME parameter) for [IDCAMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-using-access-method-services), then execute IDCAMS to rename your dataset.

Comment: The above. This is a topic that comes up on IBM-MAIN from time to time and people are always disappointed that it cannot be done via an initiated job. You could write a REXX script if you aren't comfortable with USS.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are loading the jobs using `JOBTRAC/CONTROL-M` schedulers,
   getting the date in required format is possibly easy. The format
   could be **'OSYMD'**, which will be replaced by scheduler on the fly
   before it loads the job. It has got many formats to pacify the need.
2. You can also make use of a JCL utility, *which i dont remember exactly but I would*. This takes the file name from a SYSIN dataset and makes as the DSN name of the output. The SYSIN dataset can be created in the previous step by using a simple `DFSORT &DATE commands`. Do lemme know if you need syntax, i prefer to google and handson.