# Incude the year from last month's date in the DSN using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort

I have a request similar to the "JCL for previous month-year in dataset name" question. The answer to that question used an ALTER statement, which assumes knowledge of the date. I have JCL to append the year to the DSN, however in January, I need the previous year. I think this is possible with the help of SYNCSORT or DFSORT, but am not experienced with either of these. Any assistance is appreciated.

Here is the current JCL:

```
//B999999X JOB (80594,XXX),'MAKE DATE',                      
//         CLASS=C,MSGCLASS=C,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                 
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=EZACFSM1                                 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=(*,INTRDR)                              
//SYSIN    DD DATA,DLM=@@                                    
//B8025501 JOB (,9999),'TESTING',                            
//         CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=C,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=&SYSUID  
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                  
//FILE01   DD DSN=B999999.TEST.MYFILE.FUEL&YR2,              
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                       
//            UNIT=SYSDA,                                    
//            SPACE=(CYL,(10,10),RLSE),                      
//            DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)              
/*                                                           
@@
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314232/624463) to the question you reference first states "The best solution for this is to use the features of your job scheduler."  *That remains the best answer.*  That I showed how something *could* be done was not intended to imply I thought it was the best or most maintainable method.

You could do this with [Rexx](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=tsoe-zos-rexx-reference), or a [Unix System Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-unix-system-services) shell script, or an [awk](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-awk-process-programs-written-in-awk-language) script, or [Perl](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/product-categories/mainframe/perl-for-zos), again constructing an [ALTER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-alter) statement to be used in a subsequent step to rename a statically-named dataset to one containing the date qualifier you desire.

There are some other techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464619/how-do-we-get-the-current-date-in-a-ps-file-name-qualifier-using-jcl/11470381#11470381).

But, if you have a job scheduler package available, you really should be using its capabilities.

Examples of the above proposed solutions follow.

Rexx program MKALTR

```
dsn = Arg(1)                                                  
Parse Value Date('O') With yy '/' mm '/' dd                   
If mm = 1 Then                                                 
  If yy > 0 Then                                              
    yy = yy - 1                                               
  Else                                                        
    yy = 99                                                    
outLine.1 = ' ALTER ' || dsn || ' - '                         
outLine.2 = ' NEWNAME(' || dsn || yy || ')'                   
outLine.0 = 2                                                 
Address TSO 'EXECIO * DISKW OUTPUT01 ( STEM' outLine. 'FINIS )'
Exit
```

JCL to run Rexx program MKALTR

```
//*
// SET &DS=MY.DATASET.NAME
//*
//CATLG    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                     
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,CATLG),                                   
//             DSN=&DS,                       
//             AVGREC=U,                                        
//             LRECL=80,                                        
//             RECFM=FB,                                        
//             SPACE=(80,(1,1))                                 
//*                                                             
//MKALTER  EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1B,PARM='MKALTR &DS'
//SYSEXEC  DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=dataset.where.rexx.code.resides                  
//SYSTSPRT DD  SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSTSIN  DD  DUMMY                                            
//OUTPUT01 DD  DISP=(,PASS),                                     
//             AVGREC=K,                                        
//             LRECL=80,                                        
//             RECFM=FB,                                        
//             SPACE=(80,(2,1))                                  
//*                                                             
//DOALTER  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                      
//SYSIN    DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.MKALTER.OUTPUT01         
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                                          
//*
```

Shell script mkaltr

```
let "mon=`date +'%m'`"     
let "yr=`date +'%y'`"      
if [ $mon -eq 01 ]         
then                       
  let "outyr=$yr-1"        
fi                         
echo \ ALTER $1 -          
echo \ \ NEWNAME\($1$outyr\)
```

JCL to run shell script mkaltr

```
//*
// SET &DS=MY.DATASET.NAME
//*
//CATLG    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                         
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,CATLG),                       
//             DSN=&DS,          
//             AVGREC=U,                            
//             LRECL=80,                             
//             RECFM=FB,                            
//             SPACE=(80,(1,1))                     
//*                                                 
//MKALTER  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,                       
// PARM='SH /path/to/script/mkaltr &DS'    
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,PASS),                        
//             AVGREC=U,                            
//             LRECL=80,                            
//             RECFM=FB,                            
//             SPACE=(80,(2,1))                     
//STDERR   DD  SYSOUT=*                             
//*                                                 
//DOALTER  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                          
//SYSIN    DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.MKALTER.STDOUT
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                             
//*
```

Shell script mkaltr using awk

```
date +"$1 %m %y" | awk '                             
{                                                    
yr = $3                                              
if ( $2 = 1 ) yr -= 1                                
if ( yr > 100 ) yr -= 100                             
printf( " ALTER %s -\n NEWNAME(%s%2d)\n", $1, $1, yr )
}'
```

JCL to run shell script mkaltr

```
//*
// SET &DS=MY.DATASET.NAME
//*
//CATLG    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                         
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,CATLG),                       
//             DSN=&DS,          
//             AVGREC=U,                            
//             LRECL=80,                            
//             RECFM=FB,                            
//             SPACE=(80,(1,1))                     
//*                                                  
//MKALTER  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,                       
// PARM='SH /path/to/script/mkaltr &DS'   
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,PASS),                        
//             AVGREC=U,                             
//             LRECL=80,                            
//             RECFM=FB,                            
//             SPACE=(80,(2,1))                     
//STDERR   DD  SYSOUT=*                             
//*                                                  
//DOALTER  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                          
//SYSIN    DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.MKALTER.STDOUT
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                             
//*
```

Perl program mkaltr

```
if ( @ARGV ) {                                                         
  $dsn = shift( @ARGV );                                                
} else {                                                               
  die "dataset name required";                                         
}                                                                      
                                                                        
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
if ($mon == 0) {                                                       
  $year -= 1                                                           
}                                                                      
if ($year >= 100) {                                                    
  $year -= 100;                                                         
}                                                                      
printf (" ALTER %s -\n NEWNAME(%s%2d)\n", $dsn, $dsn, $year);
```

JCL to run Perl program mkaltr

```
//*
// SET &DS=MY.DATASET.NAME
//*
//CATLG    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                              
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,CATLG),                            
//             DSN=&DS,               
//             AVGREC=U,                                 
//             LRECL=80,                                 
//             RECFM=FB,                                  
//             SPACE=(80,(1,1))                          
//*                                                      
//MKALTER  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,                            
// PARM='SH perl /path/to/perl/program/mkaltr &DS'
//STDOUT   DD  DISP=(,PASS),                             
//             AVGREC=U,                                 
//             LRECL=80,                                 
//             RECFM=FB,                                 
//             SPACE=(80,(2,1))                          
//STDERR   DD  SYSOUT=*                                  
//*                                                      
//DOALTER  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                               
//SYSIN    DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.MKALTER.STDOUT    
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                                  
//*
```