# JCL append date/time to a file?

Tags: jcl

How do I add the current date/time to a file in JCL?

For example, from the JCL:

```
//INPUT DD *
CGQ-TEST.ISQCQ.NET
ASCII
LOCSITE SBD=SYSP.FTP.RCAMSI
SENDSITE
PUT    'TJ.UTJ0IR86.BC814.HDR'  BC814001.TMP
APPEND 'TJ.UTJ4IR86.BC(0)'      BC814001.TMP
APPEND 'TJ.UTJ0IR86.BC814.TRL'  BC814001.TMP
RENAME BC813001.TMP BC814001.TXT
CLOSE
QUIT
```

I need the file BC814001.TXT to actually be BC814001.20160930.110900.ent, where 20160930.110900 is current date and time (YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS format).

Comment: You can write a program to produce the INPUT lines for the JCL as a QSAM file output.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the features of your job scheduling package (Control-M or one of its competitors).  It's usually the most maintainable.  Talk to your production control staff.

If for some reason that won't work for you, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998085/624463).

Answer (score 0):

The convention fd dataset level qualifiers limits you only to 8 characters per section (space between dots) and it should start with a character not a number.

> Each name segment (qualifier) is 1 to 8 characters, the first of which must be alphabetic (A to Z) or national (# @ $). The remaining seven characters are either alphabetic, numeric (0 - 9), national, a hyphen (-). Name segments are separated by a period (.).

For z/OS environments I would go with 'day of the year' for the actual date. For example in your case  - BC814001.**D2016274**.**T110900**.ent.

To get the current date and time You can refer to the TSO DATE and TSO TIME via REXX and format them the way You like (examples here http://www.rexxla.org/rexxlang/mfc/datec.html) then pass them as a variable to your SYSIN statement.

Regards,
Jarek.